# Input Mask for hexadecimal number in HTML5/js

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, validation

I need to create an input mask that has the following filters:

- 10 character length (I use with the HTML "maxlength" and "minlength" attributes)
- Characters in uppercase (I found a js function)
- Only accepting hexadecimal numbers ([A-F] - [0-9])
  In this last check I can't find any functions or libraries.

How can I create a mask that does this control?
Has anyone already used or implemeted something like this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Basicly `<input pattern="[A-F0-9]{10}">` does all the required checks ...

Comment: For some reason `pattern` attribute is currently not listed in the MDN documentation, but some information can be found from the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern).

Comment: @Sebastiano why would you use a js function for uppercase when you can just use the css text-transform: uppercase; ? Unnecessary use of js

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks, it's better in CSS!

Comment: @Teemu, I would to avoid the input of invalid char.
For example, I can't type the "Z" character.

Comment: Hey, the same RegEx pattern can be used in an input event too, though I personally hate GUIs which prevent me to enter anything I want.

Comment: Replace all the non-hex characters with the empty character: `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-F0-9]/g, '')`, but you obviously can't have realtime detection of the length of the input. And that's the reason, why not to favor realtime filtering of the entered values, you've to do validation also afterwards, why to validate multiple times ..?

Comment: Thanks @Teemu for your script. But this accept only decimal number, if I type "F", this character is deleted.
I try this: `onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-F0-9]/g, '')">`

Comment: [How is that](https://jsfiddle.net/v9dx5or8/)? And I was talking about using `input` event ... And don't use online events.

Comment: I resolve using `/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/g'`